# Put a Rails app in public git, keep private details private

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, github

I have a Rails app which isn't really a 'shareable' app exactly, but I'd still like to put it in a public git(hub) repo. Why? Well, mainly because I actually want to share the code with other interested people working in my field.  A free github repo doesn't hurt, but if I didn't actually want to share the code too, I'd just pay for it, sure.

### basic context

So the issue is keeping 'private' details out of the git repo. What are private details? Well, Rails does a pretty good job of isolating them. Sometimes they are seperate files, such as ./config/database.yml, or a few other app-specific (not default Rails) ./config/x files.  In other cases, there may sadly be single lines in otherwise desired-shareable files, but not sure about that.

What I'm asking now is **NOT** actually help in finding all the places that are 'private' in a Rails3 app. Nope, that was just some context for the basic problem.

### simple way to manage the private stuff

What I'm actually asking for is suggestins to use for *mechanisms* to keep the private stuff "somewhere else" and merge it into an app checked out of a public git repo.

I know the basic idea is "Well, keep them somewhere else, your choice, and then copy them in." But, yeah, where? (another private git repo? A shared file system?), and how to manage the 'copying'? ruby/rails people love automating things and automating best practices, I'm thinking there's got to be a tool for this, or at least someone that has some suggestions for best practices?

### what i want

- It needs to be **very simple**. So simple that I can leave instructions for hypothetically barely competent colleagues covering deploying an app (combining public repo with private data), as well as changing/adding/committing 'private data'.
- It should cover whole files of 'private data', and *ideally* also single lines in otherwise public files, although that *might* not be neccesary, but the ideal tool/process would do it.
- App will be deployed/checked out/setup on *multiple* hosts, and it should be easy to check it out on a brand new host without any special setup on that host. Likewise, with any host account. Same as an ordinary git checkout is not a problem in those circumstances, right?
- snapshotting/dependency management. Here's one that might have to be sacrificed, but it'd be nice. private config changes sometimes, right?  With an ordinary 'single git repo' setup, your private data is snapshotted and managed along with all the rest of your code. It's quite easy to see what version of 'private data' config goes with what version of the rest of the code, because it's just automatic -- you do a git checkout of a particular snapshot, and you get, well, the state of all code including private data at that snapshot. It would be nice to preserve this feature with a 'private data in seperate place' plan, so it's still possible to know what version of private data goes with exactly what git snapshot.... but this might not be feasible. 
  ** This requirement first made me think of "oh, just use git submodules, private data in a private git repo, the public git repo links to it with git submodule." That'd work if the 'private data' was a single directory (the entirety of that directory, and only that directory), but I'm not sure that's the case with a Rails app. Ideally *some* of ./config can be shared, and private data *might* be somewhere else. But I suppose one option would be just making sure all private data is in 'config', and keeping ALL of config 'private' even though you don't really need to.  Not ideal, if there's a better solution, but I suppose it's one approach.

### So?

Any ideas? Are there tools that already exist for this? That are good? Or if not tools, suggestions as to approaches or best practices?  (If I can figure out a killer way to do this that is elegant and powerful, I might possibly write a tool to automate it. Right now, I'm still not even sure about what the 'right' way to do it is.)

Answer (score 1):

- Refactor all the 'private' one liners into constants defined in config/secrets.yml and all your 'secret' files into config/secrets/. Pack these into a tar ball and distribute it privately to your collaborators. To version these secrets, keep the md5sum of the tar ball in a versioned file e.g. config/secrets.tar.md5. Write a rake task that expands the tar ball over your app only if the md5sum matches the versioned md5sum.
- You could encrypt each of those secret files with a symmetric key and then distribute only the key, but this puts your secrets in public (albeit in encrypted form) and relies on everyone having + correctly using something like GPG.
- In the first case, deploying the app with the secrets would be as simple as moving the tar ball to the right place and running a rake task.
- You could include the md5sum in the filename of the tar ball, meaning that from a version of secrets.tar.md5 in the repo you could identify the specific tar of secrets associated with that version.

Comment: this is an interesting idea. Where would you keep the tar ball? "as simple as moving the tar ball to the right place" -- not always so simple, if you can't find it, don't remember where it's supposed to be, then you realize your account doens't have access to where it is, have to figure out where the 'right place' to put it is, etc. Any suggestions?

Comment: actually putting the tarball encrypted in the repo is an interesting idea -- but we still have the same problem with where to keep and how to (privately, locally) distribute the key -- if that's solved satisfactorily, might as well just use whatever the solution is on the tarball itself. And either way, keeping the connection between sha commit of the repo and md5 hash of the corresponding 'secrets' seems an annoying manual process. Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to share your project with the public I would factor the secrets out in a separate GEM, which is hosted on [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/) and give each collaborator:

- A own account (max. 5 for free) or
- Shared Username/Password or
- SSH-Key

If you don't need to share i would use [bitbucket.org](https://bitbucket.org/) for the whole project since the free accounts only allow private projects.

Comment: yeah, not interested in that solution, although I know it works sometimes, I have experience with 'making it into a gem', and the extra abstraction DOES make things more complicated in ways not justified for this particular situation. thanks though!